# how to visualize the variation of hyperparam and best score

Tags: deep-learning, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am trying to adjust my model by choosing the best hyperparams (number of layers, number of neurons of each layers, batch size...) using GridSearchCV (it is done by printing the best score value). but i would like to plot the variation of those hyperparams with the mean score (or accuracy) of the model. it means that i would like to plot all single
combination of hyperparams with their results.
Here is my code, just to find best hyperparams:

```py
    def create_model(layers, activation ,optimizer):
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Conv1D(5, (3), activation=activation, input_shape=(5,1)))
      model.add(Flatten())
      for i, nodes in enumerate(layers):
         model.add(Dense(nodes, activation=activation))

      model.add(Dense(3, activation="sigmoid"))
      model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
      return model



    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn =  create_model, verbose=0)
    

    #hyperparams
    batch_size = [32,64,128]
    layers = [[128],[128,128],[32],[32,32]]
    activations = ['relu','sigmoid']
    optimizers=['adam','SGD','RMSprop']
    epochs=[200,400]


    param_grid = dict(layers = layers, activation = activations, batch_size = batch_size ,epochs=epochs, optimizer = optimizers)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid)
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

    [grid_result.best_score_,grid_result.best_params_] #out below
```

**out**:

```
[0.7661691506703695,
{'activation': 'relu',
 'batch_size': 64,
 'epochs': 150,
 'layers': [128, 128],
 'optimizer': 'SGD'}]
```